# Issue in building IONIC 3 Application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, build, ionic3

Every time I try to build the ionic app using the ionic cloud server it always fails , like in this image :

[image]

here's my system info

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 2.0.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.3
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.0
OS         : Windows 7
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 5.0.3
```

after trying more and more , it push this error :

[image]

---

I tried to build android locally - it also push this error : [image: http://i.imgur.com/y8SLFUb.png]

I want to build it anyway - locally or on the cloud - anyway !!